# Chrome font size decreased drastically for no apparent reason

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

I just restarted Chrome after a crash and the font size had decreased significantly in some areas of certain websites and not others.  It is not due to the zoom level being changed and the DirectWrite setting was not changed.  I even restored all the settings to defaults and it was not fixed.  Can anyone offer a possible explanation or fix?

Answer (score 0):

You can manually adjust the font size for web pages using [these instructions](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95416?hl=en). It might not be ideal, although if it's a website issue you can override it using that.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the three bars in the top right corner of chrome, click settings, click advanced settings,and scroll down until you see the web content catagory. There are some options there that may be useful. [image: preview]